# How to read special characters from .csv files in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, csv, utf-8, exceljs

I want to read .csv files which contains special characters (polish language).

I'm using ExcelJs to read .csv:

```
    var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    workbook.csv.readFile(uploadsPath + "/" + filename, {delimiter: ';'})
        .then(function (worksheet) {
            var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);

            console.log(worksheet.getRow(3).getCell(7).value);
        });
}
```

With this code I'm getting "Wroc�aw" instead of "Wrocław".

I tried using encoding:

```
    var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    workbook.csv.readFile(uploadsPath + "/" + filename, {encoding: 'utf-16le'})
        .then(function (worksheet) {
            var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);

            console.log(worksheet.getRow(3).getCell(7).value);
        });
}
```

But then I'm getting this error:

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "buf" argument must be one of type Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type object

How to deal with it?

Comment: In the second variant, should not the encoding be `utf16le`? And should not the `delimiter` be also included in the options?

Comment: I am not sure if the part of the word would be decoded properly if the encoding is UTF-16 and the first example read it as UTF-8. Could it be some ANSI encoding for the Polish language? Like Windows-1250 or ISO-8859-2? If so, you may need decoder like [iconv-lite](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite).

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt, with utf16le and delimiter error is the same. I just tried with the iconv-lite and ANSI encoding and results are: Wroc�aw for Windows-1250, and Wroc?aw for ISO-8859-2.

Comment: Maybe try other ones with this letter? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%81#Computer_usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a simple solution.

I created function

```
function changeEncoding(path) {
    var buffer = fs.readFileSync(path);
    var output = iconv.encode(iconv.decode(buffer, "win1250"), "utf-8");
    fs.writeFileSync(path, output);
}
```

I simply reading file, and with the help of iconv-lite, firstly decoding from win1250 and then saving the file with utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

First I think ł is a utf-8.

Try printing it in the browser, it may be the console that make it look like this

Comment: I'm inserting it into the database and it's the same problem.

Comment: Is the DB utf-8?